# Select the same file on Vuetify component v-file-input

Tags: vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am building a web app using nuxt, vuetify 2.x, and typescript.

I want to upload file using v-file-input but have some issue upon selecting the same file.

For example, when I select some file and then close the dialog without saving it,
I cannot select the same file(i.e.@change is not firing)

what I have tried:

```
<v-file-input 
  accept="image/png, image/jpeg" 
  ref="imageUploader"
  @click="resetImageUploader"
  placeholder="upload image"
  prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
  @change="changeImage"
></v-file-input>
```

script:

```
 methods: {
    resetForm() {
      (this.$refs.form as HTMLFormElement).reset();
    },
    resetImageUploader() {
      (this.$refs.imageUploader as any).reset();
    },
}
```

(resetForm() is called when dialog is closed)

I've tried resetting imageuploader when the input form is clicked, but it did not work.

I've tried `(this.$refs.imageUploader as any).value = ''` instead of `reset()` but it did not work.

Btw, When I select the file, clear icon appears like this
[image]
If I clear the form by clicking this icon, I can select the same file..

Does anyone have idea how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try to do like below to reset

```
<v-file-input 
  accept="image/png, image/jpeg" 
  ref="imageUploader"
  :value="internalVal"
  @click="resetImageUploader"
  placeholder="upload image"
  prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
  @change="changeImage"
></v-file-input>
```

script:

```
methods: {
    resetImageUploader() {
      this.internalVal = []
    },
}
```

Comment: actually, `(this.$refs.imageUploader as any).value = ''`  gave an error `Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders` and that's why I used reset(). Your suggestion gives the same error, and it gives an another error while file reading `Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'`

Comment: share your code in js fiddle or any other

Comment: and updated the post that should resolve your issue